# why my view Returns a null value of id to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

It is my view from which i am want to return the Id

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td> Id </td>
        <td>  Name  </td>
        <td>  Age </td>
        <td> Date Of Joining  </td>
        <td>  Address  </td>
        <td>  Department  </td>
        <td> Action  </td>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var nn in Model){
    <tr>

        <td> @nn.Staff_Id </td>
        <td> @nn.Staff_Name </td>
        <td> @nn.Age </td>
        <td> @nn.DO_Joining </td>
        <td> @nn.Address </td>
        <td> @nn.Deptt </td>
        <td> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditStaff", "Home", new {id= nn.Staff_Id })  |   @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveStaff", "Home", new {id= nn.Staff_Id })</td> 
    </tr>
```

} 
This is the Controller to which id will be passed as a perameter

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditStaff(int id)
    {
        Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

        var Staff = db.TblStaffs.Where(m => m.Staff_Id == id).ToList();
        return View(Staff);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditStaff(TblStaff obj)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This is the Action Rout **Creat** that will appear for the first time

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Creat", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

and then i have a Link in this view to the **ShowStaff** controller

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show All Staff", "ShowStaff")
```

I have passed the `id` to the controller `EditStaff`, but when I run the project and click on the link **Edit** in front of any staff Member, it gives me error like this

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'idd' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditStaff(Int32)' in 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

I have spent number of days on it but can't fix it. Pleas any help me any body regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditStaff", "Home", new {id= nn.Staff_Id }, null)
```

Try this code for ActionLink. 
If you are providing 4 parameters in Action Link then 3rd parameters is used for `routeValues` and 4th parameters is `htmlAttributes`. 
You need to pass 5 parameters. 5th parameter `null` is `htmlAttributes`.
Regards

Comment: Tried as same you.. but now the error is like this    "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.TblStaff]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type" 'MvcApplication1.Models.TblStaff'

Comment: By the error, it says what you are passing to view is List (Collection of TblStaff) but You should pass it single object of TblStaff. Hope this will help you. var Staff = db.TblStaffs.Where(m=>m.Staff_Id==id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: You are welcome Riaz. Please mark it as answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are passing a parameter of `id` but the controller is looking for `idd`

This:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditStaff", "Home", new {id= nn.Staff_Id })
```

Should be this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditStaff", "Home", new {idd= nn.Staff_Id })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer  i tried as you told me, but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved by implementing this code with the help of Taswar, thaks a lot

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditStaff(int id)
    {
        Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

        var Staff = db.TblStaffs.Where(m => m.Staff_Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(Staff);
    }
```